# define macro in makefile for visual studio C++ build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile, nmake

I have two exe which use the same .dll through explicit linking, both do some specific work, which are differentiated through some macros. I have created a make file to build the dll, now how to define that macro in makefile, so that I can generate respective dll for my use.
while my build is on windows, and I am using visual studio compiler, any input will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `make`, you can set macros on the command-line. These macros become read-only during the `make` run (in other words, they override any assignments that you may attempt inside the Makefile).

So, create a make-based VisualStudio project. For the *Debug* configuration ensure it runs

```
make TARGET=Debug
```

and for the *Release* configuration

```
make TARGET=Release
```